# Print front and back from an array c++

Tags: c++

> how can i print from array once from back and once from front c++?

***for examble:***

```
char c[] = { 'A','B','C','D' };
for (int i = 0; i < size(arr); i++)
{
    cout << c[i]; 
}
```

the output will be ABCD

but the output that i want should be **ADBC**

print one from front and one from end **c[0],c[3],c[1],c[2]**

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y5dEKfr61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use. Here we iterate for only half number of times the size of the array. Note that this assumes you have even number of elements in the array.

```
int main()
{
    char c[] = { 'A','B','C','D','E' };
    std::size_t len = std::size(c);
    //---------------------v------------->divide by 2 so that we iterate only half the size times
   for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
   {
        std::cout << c[i]<<c[len - i - 1];
   }
   if (len % 2) {//in case we have odd number of elements 
        std::cout << c[len/2];
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/wEY0NtmeM)

Comment: if u add item ,printed 4 items

Comment: try char c[] = { 'A','B','C','D','F'};